# How to Apply an Animation for the EditText's hint?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, animation

i am changing an EditText's hint through java by `editText.setHint(" ");` ,

how can i apply a transition or animation to the hint text when it's changed?

what am trying to do is like this, but for the hint text when i change it in java code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuBAM.gif

Answer (score 2):

Use Floating hint EditText:

In gradle add

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

use TextInputLayout in xml layout should like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/tilayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
       ------
        android:hint="yourhint"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I can't see any animation gets displayed when i change the hint text through java

Answer (score 1):

add compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0' in gradle dependencies

use TextInputLayout for animation in xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputServer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextErrorAppearance">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ........./>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I can't see any animation gets displayed when i change the hint text through java

Comment: To show as like in the link, I think it uses textView for the hint. Use textView and setText method to set new hints. then apply animation from the bottom to up movement of text before setText.

Answer (score 1):

i performed an animation to the editText by:

```
hintTextTransition = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

editText.startAnimation(hintTextTransition);
```